# Elements on page hide after scale increase

Tags: html, css

I use jQuery to change scale of my web page. Here is the code:

```
<script>
    var currFFZoom = 1;
    var currIEZoom = 1;

    function plus(){
        var step = 0.1;
        currFFZoom += step;
        if (currFFZoom > 10) currFFZoom = 10;
        $('body').css('transform','scale(' + currFFZoom + ')');
    };
    function minus(){
        var step = 0.1;
        currFFZoom -= step;
        $('body').css('transform','scale(' + currFFZoom + ')');
    };
</script>
```

It works fine, but when i increase the scale, some elements moves out of the browser edge and I can't scroll page to them. So, they become unreachable.

[PICTURE OF MAILFUNCTION](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yLu3O.jpg)

How I can fix it?

Comment: Did you try using css's `overflow`?

Comment: @Aer0 No, where should I paste it?

Comment: You may provide a sample of your code as a fiddle. Could help figuring out your problem.

Anyways, here is what `overflow` does.

Comment: @Aer0 I think, I'll need to paste here all my site html code. Maybe in chat or I can paste here a link to my site??

Comment: Just use https://jsfiddle.net/ to paste the broken part in, so we can help properly.

Comment: @Aer0 You see, I think nothing is broken. Simply I just forgot something. OK, I made a picture for you [PICTURE](https://yadi.sk/i/Apj7Y3nTmwFGz)  and http://176.112.192.242:4678/ - site itself

Comment: Scale simply 'bloats' up your whole elements. This simply leads to the point that you can't see your elements, if they reach a scale rate which is too big for the space they've got.
I'm not sure what exactly you want to approach, but maybe increasing the font-size of your body would lead to the expected behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I solved the problem. First, I changed

```
html
  { height: 0%; }
```

And width needs to be calculated using jquery. This code should be bind to some event handler (button click or something else):

```
currFFZoom = $('body').css('transform','scale');
$('html').width(currFFZoom*100 + '%');
```

Worked for me. The whole page is scrollable